# neither @RequestBody nor @RequestParam work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I want to make a PUT call in spring.

this is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/magic", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    TodoDTO magic(@RequestBody String id){
        return service.magic(id);
    }
```

because i want to pass a id string in the call.

the problem is, i receive this

```
{
  "timestamp": 1486644310464,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "message": "{\n\t\"id\":\"589c5e322abb5f28631ef2cc\"\n}",
  "path": "/api/todo/magic"
}
```

if i change the code like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/magic", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    TodoDTO magic(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id){
        return service.magic(id);
    }
```

i receive

```
{
  "timestamp": 1486644539977,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
  "message": "Required String parameter 'id' is not present",
  "path": "/api/todo/magic"
}
```

i make the same call, a PUT at link http://localhost:8080/api/todo/magic
with the body

```
{
    "id":"589c5e322abb5f28631ef2cc"
}
```

which is the id of one object in my db.

my question is, how can i achieve my goal? if i pass the param in the link, like api/todo/magic/589c5e322abb5f28631ef2cc, with @PathVariable, it works

Comment: _"with @PathVariable, it works"_ Then use it. And don't use `PUT` if you don't send data.

Comment: @zeroflagL isn't it a anti-pattern to send data in the URL? it was just a test, that's the reason for a not-do-anything-at-all method :)

Comment: If the point of your method is to return an item with or based on a certain id, then the id is not really data. If the id actually is data then you are right and it should be sent as body. But based on the error message you didn't do that.

Comment: @zeroflagL then what do you understand by data? A image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own custom class like below

```
Class Request
{
private String id;
//getter and setter
}
```

And change method to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/magic", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    TodoDTO magic(@RequestBody Request request){
        return service.magic(request.getId());
    }
```

You can take id in url also and use @Pathvariable in method signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/magic/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
        TodoDTO magic(@PathVariable String id){
            return service.magic(request.getId());
        }
```

Comment: is there any case where this should be prefered instead of a simple Map?

Comment: Reason for **not** using a map: 1) The solution suggested offers you a type-safe access to an expected input, a map forces you to use get the data using a key and check if the type is what you expect, before being usable. 2) Also clear for other developers that read the code. 3) It allows automatic API-doc generation (using spring fox). 4) If configured correctly, Jackson mapper can warn users if they use incorrect request values while a map accepts any property from the body. 5) If you have nested JSON structures, you'll end up with maps in maps (or even conversion-errors).

Answer (score 2):

When you're using `@RequestBody String id` it expects just a string:

```
"589c5e322abb5f28631ef2cc"
```

If you want to send an object with `id` field like

```
{
    "id":"589c5e322abb5f28631ef2cc"
}
```

you should create a class with `id` field and modify method's signature to get this class instead of `String`.

Comment: and if i have 2 params, just separate them with a comma?

Comment: No, because of `@RequestBody` represents the whole request body, in case of 2 params you have to create a class for them (or you `Map`).

Comment: so this option is just for 1 param. thank you for this shortcut!

Answer (score 0):

While creating a wrapper class as suggested in the other answers will work, I think it may be possible to avoid this overhead and simply use a Map.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/magic", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    TodoDTO magic(@RequestBody Map<String, String> data){
        return service.magic(data.get("id");
}
```

Comment: this seems to be the best option, because it does not need extra classes. and if i want 2 params, just call, data.get("foo")?